# Are there any limitations for angular pipes?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In my application I am using pipe a couple of times.
[my html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ntx6B.png)

And this is how my pipe looks like

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'highlightSearch',
  pure: false
})
export class HighlightSearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args: any): any {
    // console.log('args', args);
    if (value && args && args.trim()) {
      console.log('args', args);
      return value.replace(new RegExp( '(' + args + ')', 'gi'), '<b>$1</b>');
    }
    return value;
  }

}
```

And when I run my application, I could see several log statements in my console.
[console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUlty.png)
This seems like I am not using the pipe in right approach. Could someone please shed light on this.

Comment: Read about the difference between pure and impure pipe. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#pure-and-impure-pipes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impure pipes are executed on each change detection, which **could** be bad for performance, **depending** on your page. If you can, always aim for pure pipes.

Pure pipes only execute when their input values change.